# Google Translate set English as Default so when translate back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'en,zh-CN', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Above is my google translate code.

I have 2 language for my site

1 - English ( Default Language ) 
2 - Chinese

So when I switch to chinese, i want to switch back, I use the language bar and i choose english, the page did not return original version(turn off translation). How do I achieve turn off translation by change language back to english without using the Google bar Popup at top

Answer (score 0):

You can simply trigger a page reload with the translate option off so it defaults to English? Add a listener so when you switch back to English, it reloads the page without activating the translate to Chinese script.